# lxml XPath gobbles an element from the next record

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xpath, lxml

I am using lxml to obtain `name`s from each record via `XPath`. For some reason `XPath` always fetches first `name` from the next record, despite that I feed it only one record at a time. In addition, it also fetches the same name again when the next record is loaded. What am I doing wrong?

**Example: parse the following `sample.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<records>
  <REC>
      <name>Alpha</name>
      <name>Beta</name>
      <name>Gamma</name>
  </REC>
  <REC>
    <name>Delta</name>
  </REC>
</records>
```

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from lxml import etree

class Nam:
    XPATH = '/records/REC/name'
    def __init__(self):
        self.xp = etree.XPath(self.XPATH) 

    def getvals(self, doc):
        for no, el in enumerate(self.xp(doc)):
             print("{} val: {} ".format(no, el.text))

        print()                    


def main():
    nam = Nam()
    context = etree.iterparse("sample.xml", events=('end',), tag='REC')
    for event, elem in context:
        print("Element: {}".format( etree.tostring(elem).decode()))
        nam.getvals(elem)

        elem.clear()
        while elem.getprevious() is not None:
            del elem.getparent()[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
Element: <REC>
      <name>Alpha</name>
      <name>Beta</name>
      <name>Gamma</name>   </REC>

0 val: Alpha 
1 val: Beta 
2 val: Gamma 
3 val: Delta

Element: <REC>
    <name>Delta</name>   </REC>

0 val: Delta
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `iterparse` emits an event that doesn't mean that it has only parsed the input up to the current element, it may actually have already parsed beyond that point as [while you iterate over it](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/35316b0/src/lxml/iterparse.pxi#L183) it [parses the input file in chunks](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/35316b0/src/lxml/iterparse.pxi#L218) of a [fixed size](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/35316b0/src/lxml/iterparse.pxi#L3).

That however means there is no guarantee how much of the input xml has already been parsed, so for a start event you shouldn't try to access an elements content (other then its attribute) as in may not have been parsed yet and you should not try to access any of the following siblings in either start or end events.

In this case your sample xml is very short, so it's being parsed as a single chunk. Your xpath expression is rooted, so it will always return all matching elements of a document regardless of the given element.

Given that you only handle `REC` tags anyway, your xpath expression should probably be `./name` instead.